# Extract substring between `\"` with nom

Tags: rust, nom

From input `"\"Name 1\" something else"` I want to extract `"Name 1"` and the remaining string as `" something else"`. Notice the escaped `\"`.

My current solutions is

```rs
use nom::bytes::complete::{tag, is_not};
use nom::sequence::pair;
use nom::IResult;

fn parse_between(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    let (i, (_o1, o2)) = pair(tag("\""), is_not("\""))(i)?;
    if let Some(res) = i.strip_prefix("\"") {
        return Ok((res, o2));
    }
    Ok((i, o2))
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", parse_between("\"Name 1\" something else"));
}
```

where the output is `Ok((" something else", "Name 1"))`.

Is there a better way to do this? I feel as though calling `strip_prefix` is an extra step I shouldn't be doing?

[Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4946790890450cc072a252bad112b184)

Comment: In your code, all of the `\"` escape sequences will be parsed into a literal `"` character inside the string. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`delimited`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/sequence/fn.delimited.html). Here's an example [from the `nom` docs](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/#parser-combinators):

```rust
use nom::{
  IResult,
  sequence::delimited,
  // see the "streaming/complete" paragraph lower for an explanation of these submodules
  character::complete::char,
  bytes::complete::is_not
};

fn parens(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
  delimited(char('('), is_not(")"), char(')'))(input)
}
```

Adopting it to do what you're looking for:

```rust
use nom::bytes::complete::is_not;
use nom::character::complete::char;
use nom::sequence::delimited;
use nom::IResult;

fn parse_between(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    delimited(char('"'), is_not("\""), char('"'))(i)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", parse_between("\"Name 1\" something else"));
    // Ok((" something else", "Name 1"))
}
```

Comment: I went over that docs a dozen times when I looked for something else, completely missed it now. Thanks :)